# Javascript AJAX jQuery Private Cookie Scope

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I am attempting to embed a javascript based widget on my page.  Both the widget and the page are on the same domain.

The widget makes requests to the server, and the server responds with information, including cookies.  The problem is that the cookies are then shared among all the widgets on the page AND the page itself.

Question: Does jQuery or a compatible plugin provide a facility to maintain a separate cookie scope within a javascript function, such that any cookie values returned by the server call will set cookies ONLY within that function scope, and not be shared with the browser.

Yes, I realize there are many workarounds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are scoped by the browser by domain and by path.  If your widget lives in the same page as all the other widgets and as all the rest of the page content (e.g. it's not in an iframe), then it will, by definition share the same path and same domain and thus it will share all the same cookies.

So, from a security point of view, "No" you can't segregate the cookies for your widget from the cookies in the rest of the page.  Any code in that page has access to all cookies in that page.

One major use of an iframe on a separate domain is to create a secure zone of content within the page.  That would be one solution.  But, if your content can't be in an separate domain or path iframe (for whatever content or server reasons), then you can't take advantage of the iframe capability here.

---

If this isn't a security issue, but rather is just a scoping issue where you want your widget to have it's own cookie namespace, then you can solve that issue by creating a unique prefix for each widget and having each widget only use cookie names that start with their own prefix.  For example a datapicker widget my have a prefix of "widget_date_picker" so it would use cookie names such as `"widget_date_picker_last_date"` or `"widget_date_picker_current_view"`.  This wouldn't prevent other widgets from reading or even settings these cookie values, but would allow cooperating widgets to not accidentally use the same cookie names.